# How to get linkedin followers when they have crossed 500 (i am using oauth passportjs in nodejs)

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, linkedin-api

Is there a way to get count of linkedin followers of person authenticating through oAuth in my site when they have crossed 500? for example when his followers are 600 linkedin only shows it 500, but when the followers is 450 then it shows 450. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to fetch follower counts, without using the API.
I used the [LinkedIn Follow button generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/follow-company-plugin) and included it to my page. The generated iframe has a URL that you can use, to fetch the data.

For me it looked something like this:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/pages-extensions/FollowCompany?id={COMPANY_ID}&counter=bottom&xdOrigin={YOUR_URL}&xdChannel={NOT_SURE_WHAT_THIS_IS}&xd_origin_host={YOUR_URL}
```

This approach should also work for users but I haven't tested it.
Obviously this may fail in the future, but i just couldn't get any useful information from the documentation for my specific case.

Not very clean but it works for now.